# A verb for a raise in a feeling

Tags: word-choice, word-request, idiomatic-language

> The studies conducted 10 years ago shows that the feeling of belonging
>   to the group is very weak among the members. We have no evidence that the
>   feeling _____ in the meanwhile.

I want to say that there is no evidence that now there is more feeling of belonging among the members compared to 10 years ago. What verb to use. Is "to increase" idiomatic for feeling? What about "to raise"? Or there is better options? Or maybe such meaning is better be told in a different way like:

> We have no evidence of any **raise** in the feeling of belonging among
>   the member.

?

Comment: _raise_ is not idiomatic, but _rise_ would be okay: _We have no evidence of any **rise** in..._

Comment: *Increase* would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Grew*" would be the most appropriate word. It is quite common to say that "feelings grow", certainly more idiomatic than other synonyms.

Here are some [example sentences](https://ludwig.guru/s/feeling+grew) using the expression "the feeling grew":

> - The feeling grew that the business had been force-fed, and had overreached itself.
> - As the day passed, the feeling grew in the Army of Tennessee that victory was slipping from its grasp.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feeling%20grew%2C%20feeling%20rose%2C%20feeling%20increased&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeeling%20grew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeeling%20rose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeeling%20increased%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfeeling%20grew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeeling%20rose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeeling%20increased%3B%2Cc0) compares usage of that expression against two synonyms: *rose*, and *increased*.

Comment: Does "the feeling grew" mean that the feeling was created ot that it got stronger.

Comment: @Sasan The "feeling grew" means it got stronger, or intensified. When speaking about the appearance of a feeling we tend to say that we "*got* a feeling".

Answer (score 1):

"We have no evidence that the feeling *intensified* in the meanwhile."
That would be my choice for a word other than "grew",  which also seems like a good pick.

Here is an example from the Cambridge Dictionary that uses the word in reference to feelings:

> Parenthood seems to intensify the attachment relationship with one's parents, whereas prior to the birth of children the romantic partner plays the most important role. Up

You could also reword it: "No change has been *found/seen/detected*."